# Slave species that wants to be ruled over

Tags: society, aliens, economy, alternate-reality, slavery

Let's say aliens come to Earth, then leave us a slave species that only wants to serve other beings and would not like to be freed. They are the same shape but much stronger and have the same intelligence as us but also do not require anything to sustain themselves. How would this change society if we suddenly had free labor?

Comment: Hang on, I'll ask my dog.

Comment: @user535733 There would be some differences because dogs in general do things that humans can't do. Humans can't track things by smell or run for hours nonstop. But at the same time dogs aren't exactly competing with humans for jobs.

Comment: But your creatures can do things humans can't do, work indefinitely without food and water breaking physics.

Comment: Well, my dog is about as smart as some folks I've known. He agrees that it's an imperfect match...but some important elements do match. Good boy, have a treat.

Comment: Basically *House Elves from Outer Space!*

Comment: Fit humans can run for days without stopping. We're just really slow compared to most other large land animals, dogs included.

Answer (score 3):

A species like this would not evolve naturally. Maybe the aliens hijacked an existing species via selective breeding and genetic engineering, like how human livestock came to be. However, that species would still have its own biological imperatives and needs, including an energy source and materials for self-maintenance (such as food, water, and air for animals, or sunlight, water, soil, and air for plants). In that case, they would behave like animals that were specifically bred and trained to fill whatever role it was that they were bred and trained to fill. In this case, there is no guarantee they would even survive in Earth's conditions.

Alternatively, the aliens could have created the slaves artificially, in which case they would be a sort of advanced robot and closely follow their programming. They would still require an energy source, but it might be something less familiar to us.

Note that whatever the method used and purpose is that they were created for, they have to be compatible with the sort of power structures and ideologies that dominated the alien societies. The biggest drive for human technological advancement is intra-species competition. Humans have surpassed every other species on our planet in terms of power and influence, but we still [continue to develop because we are in constant competition with other humans](https://science.howstuffworks.com/war-drive-technological-advancement.htm). There is not a single invention humans have made that we haven't tried to use for war. The alien society would need to have had a major, long-lasting source of conflict in order to develop the technologies to achieve either of these methods of slave creation, likely resource scarcity.

What motivation would those aliens have for giving us this gift? Did they somehow achieve a post-scarcity society and are trying to pull others up after them? Or is it a trick to destroy us or monitor us to make sure we don't become a threat?

Note that in terms of technology, we humans have the capacity to in the near future pass off most of our labor to machines. In fact, we already have in many fields. [How did the industrial revolution change our societies?](https://existentialcomics.com/comic/370) How did the invention of the internet change our societies? We have robotic assembly lines capable of mass-producing anything we need. Goods that were once rare and expensive to hand craft can be manufactured and shipped across the globe for mere pennies. How much has it improved our lives? How much has it been to our detriment?

[And if we pass off all of our work to benevolent nannying machines and cease to care for ourselves?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Machine_Stops) It is unlikely, given our great divides in modern society that we have created. [Relative power] is a finite resource. An ordinary person in a first-world country has access to luxuries beyond the dreams of many ancient kings, but people in a seat of power rarely make an effort to change society for the benefit of others. By raising others up, you lower yourself relative to them, and make them more likely to be able to dethrone you. Would the corporations and governments with influence on the world be willing to loosen their group, even if it is for the benefit for almost every single human? ([The answer is no.](https://daily.jstor.org/how-19th-century-scientists-predicted-global-warming/))

Answer (score 1):

**All great injustices start with ethicists**.  Just think of the Covid vaccine.  People designed it in weeks - yet we had to suffer a year of deaths and economic devastation.  Why?  *Ethics!*

Here, your aliens deposit on our planet a photosynthetically enhanced, ever-industrious species of beings that *genuinely* desires only to be told what to do.  They are easily able to take the labor out of your hands.  But whose hands?

Well, at first they fan out across the countryside and talk to people at random.  Small farmers ask them to pull the plow.  Homeowners ask them to fix the roof.  And, of course, some come to larger businesses and corporations and make themselves useful there.

Well, some of the human workers are going to be laid off, and not be able to buy the materials to hand to their new slave-species workers.  They may resent those slave-species people for taking over their jobs.  They may suspect the aliens dropped them off in order to make human work and skill obsolete, make humanity dependent on their people, until one day they flip a switch and leave Earth utterly helpless to resist being made into a slave exporter itself.

A few of those workers will express such feelings by giving slave-species members tough jobs.  Picking up dead animals from the expressway.  Catching the bullets on the rifle range.  There will be incidents.  A few videos will command the entire attention of the people, and make them realize that *they* are all much too brutish and despicable to occupy such positions of responsibility!

Instead, it will be left to well-trained, certified people, from rigorously *licensed* enterprises dedicated to documenting the *proper* treatment and *careful* stewardship of their resources.  These enterprises formerly hired those despicable humans out protesting the loss of their jobs through unconscionable acts of cruelty, but now they have found a new business model.  True, the abuse of the aliens may not actually end; but that is the fault of individual unreliable human employees, and evidence that even tighter control is needed going forward.

After a few rounds of consolidation, lawsuits, and carefully tailored regulations, just one corporation will be left, which holds a government license certifying that it is the *only* legal person entitled to own slaves.  It will provide all the common people's needs, at least within the meager means allowed, for the time being, to such useless parasites in government relief.

Answer (score 0):

A slave race that does all the physically strenuous work for us, and requires very little to no upkeep?

I see absolutely no problem with this!
[image]

Image from Wall-E movie, which belongs to Disney and Pixar.